# Splitting field of $x^{{p}^e}-1$ over $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'd like a hint for determining the splitting field of $x^{{p}^e}-1$ over the integers mod $p$, $\mathbb Z_p$, where $e$ is an arbitrary natural number. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: [Freshman's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic)

Comment: @achillehui that's right, I think the answer is Zmodp, I mean the splitting field in this case is $Z_p$ itself

Answer (score 2):

Approach 1: Well, there is one obvious root. What is it? What is its multiplicity? Work out the easy stuff, then go from there.

Approach 2: You're asking to solve the equation $x^{p^e} - 1 = 0$....

Comment: Is it $Z_p$ the answer?

Comment: Yep. If you don't guess the factorization, you can easily count the multiplicity of the root $1$ by seeing how many times $x-1$  divides the derivative. Or you can recognize that $1$ is the only $p$-th root of unity in a field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Thank you, I found the factorization indeed, it follows directly from the "freshman's dream".

Comment: @user59898 $x^{p^e} -1 = (x -1)^{p^e}$ and so the splitting field is just $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ itself.